# Ruby: error installing slop

Tags: ruby, rubygems, updates

I'm on Xubuntu, I tried to gem update, but I got this error, that crash my update:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing slop:
    slop requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0
```

My version of ruby is `ruby-2.0.0-p451`.

Thanks!!!

Comment: do you have more than 1 ruby installed?  Do you have more than 1 version of gem installed?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you're mentioning everything we need to know.

How did you install `ruby-2.0.0-p451`? Is it installed properly?

*I'd make sure your Ruby is installed properly.*